# How to retrieve row values from a DataTable in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to execute a sql query in c# and store the result in a `DataTable` variable. And then I want to get values from a particular row. here is my code.

```
string query = "select * from Deptment where Dname=@Dname";
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dname", comboBox1.SelectedText);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(dr);

textBox2.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
Dept_name.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
textBox1.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
No_of_Employees.Text = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();
Dept_discription.Text = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString();

con.Close();
```

But I am getting this error:

> There is no row at position 0.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you get no result. To avoid this exception add a check

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    textBox2.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
    Dept_name.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
    textBox1.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
    No_of_Employees.Text = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();
    Dept_discription.Text = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString();
}
```

and i would work with column names instead if index values like `dt.Rows[0]["Name"]`. That leads to errors when you change your table structure.

Comment: i try it your way and catch above with a error message. but it show the error message and i did not get the result.

Comment: but there is data in my sql table.

Comment: i guess the value in `@Dname` is invalid / leads to no result

Comment: i declared a string variable top of the method and assigned it to a value of my combobox. then i passed it to the @Dname.